# compose() vs. transform() vs. as() vs. map() in Flux and Mono

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Recently, I decided to try spring 5 with [projectreactor.io](http://projectreactor.io/docs) (io.projectreactor:3.1.1).

**Does anyone know what the best case of using this functions? What cons and pros of using each of them and where they should be used?**

Good examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have two broadly different categories of operators here:

## Operators that work on the `Flux` itself

### `transform` and `transformDeferred` are for code mutualization

When you compose chains of operators regularly and you have common operator usage patterns in your application, you can mutualize this code or give it a more descriptive name by using `transform` and `transformDeferred`.

The difference between the two is *when* the mutualized operators are applied: `transform` applies them at instantiation, while `transformDeferred` applies them at subscription (allowing for dynamic choice of the added operators).

Have a look at the [reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#advanced-mutualizing-operator-usage) for more details and examples.

*note: `transformDeferred` was called `compose` in versions prior to 3.3.0*

### `as`

This is a convenience shortcut to apply a `Function` to the whole `Flux` while keeping the whole code in a fluent style.

The **major differentiator with `transform*` operators** is that this one doesn't enforce a particular return type. It is all driven by the `Function` you use, and could for instance be used for testing with a `StepVerifier` in a fluent style:

```
Flux.just("test")
    .map(String::length)
    .as(StepVerifier::create)
    //from there on we're dealing with the StepVerifier API
    .expectNext(4)
    .verifyComplete();
```

The example shown in the javadoc uses this approach to convert to a `Mono` using `Mono::from`, which is a bit confusing because the return type is quite close to `Flux`.

Note that this approach can also helps with external operators that are implemented in a factory method style to "extend" the `Flux` API

Take `reactor-addons` `MathFlux` for example, and compare:

```
MathFlux.sumInt(Flux.range(1, 10)
                    .map(i -> i + 2)
                    .map(i -> i * 10))
        .map(isum -> "sum=" + isum);
```

To:

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
    .map(i -> i + 2)
    .map(i -> i * 10)
    .as(MathFlux::sumInt)
    .map(isum -> "sum=" + isum)
```

*(this can help you deal with the fact that, unlike Kotlin, Java doesn't have extension methods :) )*

## Operator that works on the data that goes through the `Flux`

`map` is all about the data. It applies a 1-1 transformation function to each element in the source, as they become available.

In the MathFlux example above, `map` is successively used to add 2 to each original integer, then again to multiply each number in the sequence by 10, then a third time at the end to produce a `String` out of each sum.

Comment: Could you update your answer please? It seems that `compose()` does not exist anymore...

Comment: Hi Simon, you have not really clarified the difference between transform and as. when to use what. Please check this question - https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2898

Comment: @RamPrakash I've edited my answer

Comment: I appreciate it Simon.

Answer (score 11):

I found the example in [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_using_the_code_transform_code_operator)  little difficult to follow

So made the below programs to wrap my head around the tranform vs compose concept.

```
fnstatefull = flux -> {
                            Flux<String> f = flux.filter(color -> {
                                //only reds are allowed
                                return color.equalsIgnoreCase("red");   

                            });
                            //applies mapping 'toUpperCase' based on the external control 'toUpper'
                            if(toUpper) {
                                f= f.map(String::toUpperCase);
                            }
                            return f;
                        };
```

**Transform**

The operator is applied at the time of *instantiation* of the flux.

fnstatefull will behave same way for both subscribers below.

```
    Flux<String> f = Flux.just("red", "green", "blue");
    toUpper = false;
    f = f.transform(fnstatefull);
    toUpper = true;

    f.subscribe(op -> log.error("ONE>>>" + op));
    toUpper = false;
    f.subscribe(op -> log.error("TWO>>>" + op));
```

Output

```
ReactordemoApplication - ONE>>>red
ReactordemoApplication - TWO>>>red
```

**Compose**

The operator is applied at the time of *subscription* to the flux.

fnstatefull will behave differently for each subscriber below.

```
    Flux<String> f = Flux.just("red", "green", "blue");
    toUpper = false;
    f = f.compose(fnstatefull);
    toUpper = true;

    f.subscribe(op -> log.error("ONE>>>" + op));
    toUpper = false;
    f.subscribe(op -> log.error("TWO>>>" + op));
```

Output

```
ReactordemoApplication - ONE>>>RED
ReactordemoApplication - TWO>>>red
```