# Difference between Flux.compose and Flux.transform?

Tags: reactive-programming, publish-subscribe, project-reactor, publisher, reactive-streams

I am learning reactive streams and working on Publishers(Flux), and working for the transformation of Flux. For this i got compose and transform methods.

Here is my code:

```
private static void composeStream() {
    System.out.println("*********Calling composeStream************");
    Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> alterMap = f -> {
                                                                return f.filter(color -> !color.equals("ram"))
                                                                        .map(String::toUpperCase);
                                                            };

    Flux<String> compose = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("ram", "sam", "kam", "dam"))
                                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                                    .compose(alterMap);

    compose.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscriber to Composed AlterMap :"+d));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

}

private static void transformStream() {
    System.out.println("*********Calling transformStream************");
    Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> alterMap = f -> f.filter(color -> !color.equals("ram"))
                                                            .map(String::toUpperCase);

    Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("ram", "sam", "kam", "dam"))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .transform(alterMap)
            .subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscriber to Transformed AlterMap: "+d));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
}
```

and here is the output, which is same for both the cases:

```
*********Calling transformStream************
ram
sam
Subscriber to Transformed AlterMap: SAM
kam
Subscriber to Transformed AlterMap: KAM
dam
Subscriber to Transformed AlterMap: DAM
-------------------------------------
*********Calling composeStream************
ram
sam
Subscriber to Composed AlterMap :SAM
kam
Subscriber to Composed AlterMap :KAM
dam
Subscriber to Composed AlterMap :DAM
-------------------------------------
```

What is the difference between the two?
Please suggest

Comment: Hey @KayV. I suggest you visit https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor. It would be much easier and faster to get an answer on your questions :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compose() vs. transform() vs. as() vs. map() in Flux and Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348706/compose-vs-transform-vs-as-vs-map-in-flux-and-mono)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### According to documentation:

> *Transform this `Flux` in order to generate a target `Flux`. Unlike `Flux#compose(Function)`, the provided function is executed as part of assembly.*

### What does it means?

If we will write a small test like next:

```
 int[] counter = new int[1];
 Function transformer  = f -> {
     counter[0]++;

     return f;
 }

 Flux flux = flux Flux.just("")
     .transform(transformer);

 System.out.println(counter[0]);

 flux.subscribe();
 flux.subscribe();
 flux.subscribe();
 System.out.println(counter[0]);
```

In the output we will observe next result:

```
 1
 1
```

Which means that transform function will be executed once during assembling of the pipe, so in other words transformation function will be executed ***eagerly***.

In turn, with `.compose` we will get next behavior for the same code

```
 int[] counter = new int[1];
 Function transformer  = f -> {
     counter[0]++;

     return f;
 }

 Flux flux = flux Flux.just("")
     .compose(transformer);

 System.out.println(counter[0]);

 flux.subscribe();
 flux.subscribe();
 flux.subscribe();
 System.out.println(counter[0]);
```

And output

```
 0
 3
```

Which means that for each subscriber transformation function will be executed separately, and we may consider that kind of execution as ***lazy***